# Does this sentence sound natural: その靴はどこで買いましたか

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, reading-comprehension

> その靴はどこで買いましたか

Should か be replaced with の? Should I say 買った instead of 買いました?

Make any sort of corrections you want, I'm trying to make my Japanese sound as native as possible.

Answer (score 3):

It's grammatically perfectly correct, but whether or not it sounds natural depends on the situation. If you're asking this question to your colleague, your sentence is perfectly natural as-is. If you're asking this question to your boss or a guest, you need to use proper keigo, like "その靴はどこでお買いになりましたか?". If you're asking this to your friend or family, then you would speak much more informally, like "その靴どこで買ったの?".

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer